# Context problem in Android example "Google Map View"

Tags: android, google-maps

I've tried to implement the [Google Map View](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) tutorial on the Android developer site, but I keep running into a problem when trying to display an AlertDialog when I click on the overlay image.  The problem is that mContext is null when calling

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
```

in HelloItemizedOverlay's onTap method because the constructor

```
public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
}
```

is never called (that I can tell) which initializes mContext.  When I replace

```
HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);
```

with

```
HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, 
                this.getApplicationContext());
```

in HelloGoogleMaps's onCreate method in order to initialize the context, I get an exception

android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

when I try to display the AlertDialog like so:

```
dialog.show();
```

I assume this tutorial has been successfully implemented by thousands of people, so I'm at a loss why no one else has run into this problem... have I missed an important step from the tutorial?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need to pass mapView's context to the HelloItemizedOverlay constructor like so:

```
HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView.getContext());
```

There is clearly an error in the tutorial's code sample. Small errors and omissions like this are not uncommon within reference documentation, especially for a large project like Android.

Comment: "Small errors and omissions like this are not uncommon within reference documentation" - true, but it doesn't have to be this way. ;-)

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319158/googlemaps-mapview-crashes-ontap-in-android) addresses the same two mistakes in the tutorial.

Comment: Because of my setup, ...(drawable, MyMapViewActivity.this.getParent()); worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

And in the constructor it seems should be:

```
super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
```

not:

```
super(defaultMarker);
```