# I am unable to draw the path between two geo coordinates. Here is the code

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

```
package com.chleon.mapviewdemo;

import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {
    Projection projection;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.ic_action_search);
        HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(
                drawable, this);
        int latitude1 = (int) (28.619087 * 1e6);
        int longitude1 = (int) (77.376867 * 1e6);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitude1, longitude1);
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Prashant",
                "I'm somewhere near delhi");

        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(17385812, 78480667);
        OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Prashant",
                "I'm in Hyderabad");

        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);

        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
    }

    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    class MyOverlay extends Overlay {

        public MyOverlay() {

        }

        public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

            Paint mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
            int latitude1 = (int) (28.619087 * 1e6);
            int longitude1 = (int) (77.376867 * 1e6);
            projection = mapView.getProjection();
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitude1, longitude1);
            GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(17385812, 78480667);
            Point p1 = new Point();
            Point p2 = new Point();
            Path path = new Path();

            projection.toPixels(point, p1);
            projection.toPixels(point2, p2);

            path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
            path.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);

            canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to draw a line connecting the two geographical coordinates given in the code.The two points are showing but I am unable to get the line that i want to draw.
I referred [Drawing a line/path on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397) but the output is not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView.getContext());

[Context problem in Android example "Google Map View"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255441/context-problem-in-android-example-google-map-view)

Comment: I am having the problem in drawing the line, not in locating the two points.